# Is this site still private?

Tags: support

Is the sitecore.stackexchange.com site still private, as in, one needs an invitation to participate?  Mark Cassidy put some stats into Slack that seemed to indicate we need a lot more participation, but if the site is only accessible to the few I can't see how that will work?

Comment: @MarkCassidy this question pre-dates the other answer by some margin - I hope I don't get penalised once I tick this off as a dupe.

Comment: I don't actually know. I was just following Roberts own example, by voting to close previous posts that now had a new answer. http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/50/do-we-really-think-we-can-convince-stack-exchange-to-not-close-the-site-on-oct-7

It's no big deal either way. Just seems better imo, that we do a little grooming.

Comment: That said; I believe your reputation stays intact. The question remains as is. It just gets locked, so no additional answers can be added and no new votes cast. Presumably on Search Engine level, SE will ignore the post as well - this I don't know however.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously committed users can send invites.

For self registration, If the user have not previously committed to the Sitecore proposal on Area51 then by following below steps he can join in private beta as well.

1. Visit the [Sitecore proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101710/sitecore) link
2. User will need to create a StackExchange account if he has not already done so on Area51 site (and later on here site as well).
3. Now open 'definition' tab click 'Follow It!'

[image: Follow the Proposal]

4. Now open 'beta' tab use the 'Visit' link from that page.

[image: Sitecore Private beta]

*P.S. If the private beta site doesn't show you logged in after last step, then Login using same Stack Exchange account that was used on Area51 Proposal*

Answer (score 2):

I do believe it's still a private beta.

However, an email invite can be sent out to invite others to join, on the right hand side of the sitecore.stackexchange.com site when logged in (at least, I have that option, I assume anyone who's committed to the idea will have that option?).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as others have said, the site is still in Private Beta.  I didn't have the "Invite Fellow Experts" option when I first joined until I got over a 150 reputation on the site. So, I am under the impression that only users that have been using the site with some regularity (enough to get past 150 rep) can invite.

I have since invited about 5 people. We need A LOT MORE!